# I can't access and read and write Folders in External Storage beyond Android M by Code

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I tested this code below Android Lollipop it it works fine:

```
File file = new File(sPath);
        File[] files = file.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File f) {
                return f.isDirectory();
            }
        });

tvFileCounter.setText("Folders count: " + files.length);
            }
        }
```

but not working after Android Lollipop.Please Help if Someone Know Why?

Comment: Which error is it throwing? Are you checking runtime permissions?

Comment: Actually I manually Permitted Permissions. now I understand it's wrong. thanks for the Comment though.

Answer (score 1):

Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app. This approach streamlines the app install process since the user does not need to grant permissions when they install or update the app. It also gives the user more control over the app's functionality; for example, a user could choose to give a camera app access to the camera but not to the device location. The user can revoke the permissions at any time, by going to the app's Settings screen.[Requesting Permissions at Runtime](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: Ya I Know, but for testing I allow Permission manually. but It turn out that is not Sufficient. Thanks for the Answer. :-)

Comment: https://www.androidhive.info/2016/11/android-working-marshmallow-m-runtime-permissions/
This blog will help you to get storage permissions

Answer (score 1):

accordin to the [doc](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) from android **M** (**api 23**) you need to ask for Runtime permission , you can ask for runtime permisison like below , a **dialog** will be opened to ask permission to user ...

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                1);


    }
```

then you do whatever you want here on `onRequestPermissionsResult`

```
  @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
            String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        if(requestCode == 1){
               if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // do whatever you want here 
            }
           }
      }
```